# Problems in javascript on devexpress 14.1

Tags: devexpress

I guess this is regarding javascript errors in my program as it does not show any errors during compilation. Errors i found in my firebug console are

1. ReferenceError: "ASPxSpreadsheetDialog is not defined"
2. TypeError: n.ui is undefined

It displays the date but could not update it. Also event like shorting does not work.

i kept updated reference of knockout,jquery and globalized js files on my layout but its not helping. i also tried the support provided by devexpress http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T113961 but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be more than a single error i was having in my program. The jquery scripts must be called before devexpress scripts and also had to configure **enableResourceMerging** and **UnobtrusiveJavascriptenableValue** in *web.config*

Answer (score 0):

The problem you reported has been researched, and [another bug](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T114839) was found in MVCxClientGridViewBatchEditHelper. These errors are either related to it or it is a completely different bug. My word of advice would be to upgrade to the recent DevExpress version and see if this helps. Otherwise, report this problem to [DevExpress support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) (or email them to support@devexpress.com) and describe the case in detail.